# Show highlighted image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, highlight

I have set an image and a background image to a UITableViewCell.
But when I click on it, it show the standard blue high-lightening and not mine.

Do you know how I can change this mecanism ?

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

You can also set the cell's selectedBackgroundView to a custom view and set its backgroundColor.

Comment: nope. I don't use backgroundcolor, I'm using backgroundView. And i can see the standard view I defined, and not the highlighted.

Comment: backgroundView is the normal backgroundView, selectedBackgroundView is the one that's used when the cell is selected, but only when it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the two UITableViewCell property backgroundView and selectedBackgoundView. iOS will do the rest.